# Problems with scrolling and zooming after rotating a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, orientation

I have the same problem as in [HERE](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/61826-problems-scrolling-zooming-after-rotating-uiimageview.html) .. Please Help!

> I have a UIViewController that
>   supports scrolling and zooming of a
>   UIImageView. It works great.
>
> I’m trying to add support for changes
>   in orientation. For various reasons, I
>   need to do this by rotating just the
>   UIImageView and not the
>   UIViewController.
>
> I have the image rotation working, but
>   if the user pinch-zooms when the image
>   is rotated, the image’s size and
>   location go bonkers (e.g., the images
>   jumps to the side, gets too small,
>   doesn’t seem to know where the extents
>   of the scroll view are, etc).
>
> The core contents of the h file:

```
@interface ImageViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

> Support for zooming:

```
-(UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return imageView;
}
```

> Support for scrolling (set after the
>   image is loaded):

```
[scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(imageView.bounds.size.width, imageView.bounds.size.height)];
```

> Support for rotating the image when
>   the orientation changes:

```
-(void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    CGFloat angle = 0;
    switch (orientation) 
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            angle = M_PI/2.0f;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            angle = -M_PI/2.0f;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            angle = M_PI;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
}
```

> I suspect the problem is that the
>   scrollView is confused because the
>   size of the image has changed due to
>   the rotation, but I’m clueless as to
>   how to fix it. Any ideas? FWIW, the
>   zooming does work if I change the
>   orientation, but then change it back
>   to "vertical" before zooming.

Comment: Try to elaborate here to get an answer. I have edited your original post. Copy paste from the link.

Answer (score 0):

Redraw your image view by removing it from the srollView and read it again.